CSRF Cookie Not Set when trying to log in django-allauth headless and NextJS+NextAuth
I've been learning Django and am trying to move from the standard templates to a separate NextJS frontend supported by Django Rest Framework.
I implemented Django-allauth (headless) on the backend and NextAuth on the frontend, but I cannot get the Login to accept my login POST (403 error with CSRF Cookie not set) despite trying multiple tips online to get a valid CSRF token.
My NextJS frontend is at localhost:3000 and my Django backend at localhost:8000. The login endpoint works from unit tests in my Django app.
Process
Submit frontend form at http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin
Django output:
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /_allauth/browser/v1/auth/login
[timestamp] "POST /_allauth/browser/v1/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 403

Django
settings.py


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "corsheaders",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.headless",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware",
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "0.0.0.0", "127.0.0.1"]
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "localhost"
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "localhost"
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000"]

# AUTHENTICATION
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authtools.User"

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation."
        + "UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by email
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]

HEADLESS_ONLY = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False

FRONTEND_URL = env("FRONTEND_URL", default="http://localhost:3000")

HEADLESS_FRONTEND_URLS = {
    "account_confirm_email": FRONTEND_URL + "/account/verify-email/{key}",
    "account_reset_password_from_key": FRONTEND_URL
    + "/account/password/reset/key/{key}",
    "account_signup": FRONTEND_URL + "/account/signup",
}

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_CHANGE_EMAIL = True

# REST FRAMEWORK SETTINGS
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser",),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
}

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('csrf-token/', get_csrf_token, name='csrf-token'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path("_allauth/", include("allauth.headless.urls")),
    ...

views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def get_csrf_token(request):
    token = get_token(request)
    response = JsonResponse({"csrfToken": token})
    response.set_cookie("csrftoken", token)
    return response

NextJS
./utils/csrfCookie.ts
export async function getCsrfToken() {
  const server_url = process.env.SERVER_URL;
  const response = await fetch(server_url + "/api/csrf-token/", {
    credentials: "include", // Important to include credentials for CSRF
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch CSRF token");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("CSRF: ", data);
  return data.csrfToken;
}

auth.ts
import { getCsrfToken } from "./utils/csrfCookie";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        let user = null;
        const server_url = process.env.SERVER_URL;
        console.log("Credentials: ", credentials);
        try {
          const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken();
          console.log("JSON CSRF: ", csrfToken);

          const response = await fetch(
            server_url + "/_allauth/browser/v1/auth/login",
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password
              }),
              credentials: "include",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
              },
            },
          );

          if (!response.ok) {
            console.error("Failed to login:", response.statusText);
            throw new Error("Failed to login");
          }

          user = await response.json();
          console.log("User retrieved: ", user);

          if (!user) {
            throw new Error("User not found.");
          }

          return { ...user, token: user.token };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Authorization error:", error);
          throw error;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});


This seems resolved now by explicitly using cookies rather than the header value
Updated ./utils/csrfCookie.ts
import cookie from 'cookie';

export async function getCsrfToken() {
  const server_url = process.env.SERVER_URL;
  const response = await fetch(server_url + "/api/csrf-token/", {
    credentials: "include", // Important to include credentials for CSRF
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch CSRF token");
  }
  // Function to get a cookie by name
  const cookies = response.headers.get('set-cookie');
  if (!cookies) {
    throw new Error("No set-cookie header found in the response");
  }

  // Parse the cookies
  const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(cookies);

  // Get the CSRF token from the parsed cookies
  const csrfToken = parsedCookies['csrftoken'];
  
  if (!csrfToken) {
    throw new Error("CSRF token not found");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("Cookie CSRF: ", csrfToken);

  return csrfToken;
}

Updated auth.ts
          const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken();
          const cookies = cookie.serialize('csrftoken', csrfToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
            sameSite: 'strict',
            path: '/'
          });

          const response = await fetch(
            server_url + "/_allauth/browser/v1/auth/login",
            {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken
              }),
              credentials: "include",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
                'Cookie': cookies
              },
            },
          );


Hi, I'm not getting the access-token after the login in the meta data, I only get authenticated = true; can you help what may be the issue?
